# Using Selenium from the browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver

I want to run and control a browser window from a web application, to automate some things (like account creation etc.) on another site.

So my question is, is there a way to do it using selenium directly from the browser, and in such a case how to do it?
I know there is selenium-webdriver for JS, but in common use cases we use it with Node.js.

The [WebDriver introduction](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) suggests that this is possible:

> It is primarily intended to allow web authors to write tests that
> automate a user agent from a separate controlling process, *but may
> also be used in such a way as to allow in-browser scripts to control a
> — possibly separate — browser.*

Comment: you could either run it on your server and present results, or use some kind of browser plug-in... embedded Java (deprecated, and no longer supported), ActiveX (still around?)... maybe an extension or add-on could do it?  Any javascript running in the browser on the client side would be inside the sandbox and not allowed to install/run a webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is: write a WebApp in such way that when it is loaded on client browser it does some actions on another website - the answer is "NO" - in order to use Selenium you need a thing called "WebDriver" this is a "program" that needs to be run on the machine where selenium is to be run (and it controls the client browser) - but running external programs from browser is not allowed.

What you can do with selenium - run the "webdriver" on a specific machine, and control/automate actions in a browser on this machine.